# 82c55 as 8 bit latches

Tags: programming, interface, latch, bus, peripheral

I'm trying to make my 82C55 function as three sets of 8-bit latches where I can choose one of them by applying the appropriate logic to A0 and A1 and lowering the WR signal to apply the data from input to desired output port.

I read online that this chip has 4 modes of operation, but I want to configure it as three addressable byte latches as I have explained.

Is it possible I can use it like that without specifically programming the chip in advance even though sources tell me data is in groups of 12 bits?

Answer (score 2):

No, the 82C55 is by default (after a reset) programmed into three input ports of 8 bits each. This is equivalent of programming 0x9B in the control register (Mode 0 all inputs).

To program the registers as outputs you will need at minimum to write 0x80 to the control register.

See the datasheet: http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/82c5/82c55a.pdf

Look at Figure 4 for details on the control register values